What will be the conditions under which- "If A and B are events such that P(A|B) = P(B|A)"
This is a rather simple question from the chapter 'Probability' given in the class 12 textbook published by NCERT.
If A and B are events such that P(A|B) = P(B|A), then
(A) A ⊂ B but A ≠ B
(B) A = B
(C) A ∩ B = φ
(D) P(A) = P(B)
Now, according to the answers, the correct option is D and I quite agree upon that as we can prove that as below
P(A|B)=P(B|A)
=> P(A intersection B)/P(B)= P(A intersection B)/P(A)
=> P(A)=P(B)
However I strongly think that option C should be equally correct.
I processed this thought through an example:
If we perform a toss on a die and take the following two events:
event A= we get an even prime number
event B= we get an odd number
Now, for these events P(A|B)=P(B|A)=0
which is because P(A intersection B)=0
i.e. A intersection B is a null set.
Please clarify my doubt and help me ascertain if I am on the right track.

@geetha290krm yeah. P(A) and P(B) are both greater than 0. No, C wont always give P(A)=P(B). For example we can consider the example I have given above regarding throwing a dice, there P(A)=1/6 and P(B)=1/2 but P(A|B)=P(B|A)=0. So, C doesnt always coincide with D.

Assume $\mathbb{P}(A) > 0,  \mathbb{P}(B) > 0$. The condition for the equality of conditional probabilities can be expressed as:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = \mathbb{P}(B \mid A),
$$
where
$$
\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{P}(B \mid A) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}.
$$
By equating the two:
$$
\frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)},
$$
we find that if $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \neq 0$, it follows that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(B).
$$
If $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = 0$, the condition is also satisfied.
Note, however, that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = 0$ does not imply that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. (However it is true that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ implies $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = 0$)
Lets look at the following counterexample:
Consider a probability space with a continuous probability distribution where the sample space $ S $ is the interval $ [0, 1] $. Define two events $ A $ and $ B $ as follows:
$$
A = \{ x \in [0, 1] \mid x \text{ is a rational number} \}
$$
$$
B = \{ x \in [0, 1] \mid x = \frac{1}{2} \}
$$
The intersection $ A \cap B = \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \right\} $ is not empty. However, the probability measure of a single point in a continuous interval $ [0, 1] $ is zero, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb{P} \left( \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \right\} \right) = 0.
$$
So option C is not necessarily true.
Option D is correct with an extra assumption that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \neq 0$

thankyou for the explanation. This actually cleared my doubts.

The textbook answer is wrong.
Assuming $P[A]$ and $P[B]$ are both nonzero so that the conditional probabilities exist, the condition $P[A|B] = P[B|A]$ can be rewritten as $$\frac{P[A \land B]}{P[B]} = \frac{P[A\land B]}{P[A]}$$ which is satisfied iff $P[A \land B] = 0$ or $P[A] = P[B]$.  So you cannot deduce (D).  Note that the former condition is not the same as (C), since $A \land B$ need only have probability zero, it doesn't have to be the empty set.

I agree with your explanation. D cannot be deduced without constraints since P(A^B) can be zero. I am not totally sure about this but if A intersection B is a null set then isnt P(A^B) always zero. you can also consider my example for context.

@GyaanM.Teli "if A intersection B is a null set then isnt P(A^B) always zero" -- In the present context, $P(A\cap B)=0$ is the definition of $A\cap B$ being a null set. But being a null set does not imply being empty.
